# Finding the dimension, rank, and nullity of a Matrix with limited information

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have to find the rank and nullity of a matrix $A$ without knowing the matrix. I am instead given that $A(v_1)=x1$ and $A(v_2)=x2$, where:
$v_1=[3,-1,1,2]$, $v_2=[1,-2,3,1]$, $x_1=(-18,9)$, and $x_2=(-6,3)$. Note $v_1$ and $v_2$ are column vectors.

I know that $A$ must be a $2 \times 4$ matrix, and its dimension should be $4$. However, I don't know how to use the information given to find the rank and nullity of $A$. If anyone could give me some hints as to how I should proceed I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ maps a four dimensional space (vectors with four entries) into a two dimensional space (vectors with two entries). This tells you that the rank of $A$ cannot be more than 2 (do you see why?). Remind that the rank is defined as the dimension of the image space of $A$. You're given two non-zero vectors in this space, you most probably know a way to check when two vectors do not span a plane. From this you will find the rank of $A$, and then you use that rank $+$ nullity equals dimension of the domain.

Edit: fixed the inversion of dimensions

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I understand that the rank must be less than or equal to 2. However, I am unsure of which sets of vectors must span a plane. Are you referring to the vectors in the two-dimensional space or the ones that they get mapped into?

Comment: It’s the other way around: $A$ maps four-dimensional vectors to two-dimensional ones.

Comment: @amd: you're right, for some reason I messed this up.

To OP: you want to know the rank of $A$, and the rank is the dimension of the image. So you want to check independence of vectors in the image of $A$, right? I plead guilty of confusing the range and domain space in my first answer which probably did not help, sorry for this.

Comment: You can edit your answer to correct it.

Comment: KeiOh, thanks for clarifying. I think I understand what to do now.